# cannot call member function without object error

Tags: c++, oop, static-members

I have a static funcA in ClassA which calls non-static funcB in classA. Although I gave object to the funcB call I still get the error: cannot call member function without object

```
void* ClassA::funcA(void *arg)
{
   ClassA *pC = reinterpret_cast<ClassA *>(arg);

   funcB(pc);
}

void* ClassA::funcB(ClassA *arg)
{

}
```

what is the reason for that?

Comment: as the error message says, you need an object. the method isn't static.

Comment: I gave pC which is object pointer. Isn't it enough?

Comment: if that were the problem, it would complain about the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

A static class method can be called without an object, like you're doing.
A regular class method needs to be called on an object, like this: `objectInstance.classMethod( arguments go here )` or `objectPointer->classMethod( arguments go here )`

Try this (after changing the signature of funcB in your class declaration to match):

```
void* ClassA::funcA(void *arg)
{
   ClassA *pC = reinterpret_cast<ClassA *>(arg);

   pC->funcB();
}

void* ClassA::funcB()
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that to call funcB it should be done via some object like:

```
pC->funcB(pC);
```

Actually this kind of code is more like C than C++ because if you are calling a method on an object you don't need to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: If `funcB` only works with one object, it should be made static, or it shouldn't take a parameter. Doing what you suggested is just redundant (presumably `pc` in the question is just a typing error and it should be `pC` instead).

Comment: @Dukeling I corrected the mistype and explained my point, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You're calling from a static method, so there's no receiver object in the scope.

Consequently, you cannot call a non-static method.

You need an object, which will receive the message: `o.funcB(pc);`

Answer (score 0):

its not a good idea to call a member function from static function , The reason why it errors out here is that the functionB is invoked from static method . the static method cannot invoke non static member functions . The reason is static function operates on classes not on objects .